# How to mark as outdated an ActiveRecord object attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a database trigger that modifies a field on `INSERT`. Then when I run `object.my_attribute` it returns `nil` instead of lets say `42`.

If I do `object.reload.my_attribute`, this is fine. But I don't want to reload the whole object or part of it unless it is necessary. And I believe code shouldn't be concerned when and how an object was created. It should just be correct.

Is it possible to mark that particular attribute as outdated and any attempt to get its value to result in a query that fetches it from database?

For example:

```rb
after_save :forget_my_attribute

def forget_my_attribute
  forget_field :my_attribute
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to make some service object where field is modified and call it when create the record. `CreateModel.call(args)` instead of   `Model.create(args)`. It will be more clear than database trigger I think

But you can do something like this

```
after_create_commit :fetch_my_attribute

def fetch_my_attribute
  self[:my_attribute] = self.class.find_by(id: id)[:my_attribute]
end
```

Or more flexible fetch attribute you need dynamically

```
def fetch_attribute(atr)
  self[atr] = self.class.find_by(id: id)[atr]
end

object.fetch_attribute(:my_attribute)
```

Comment: In theory, I can set attribute `before_save` also. An additional `find_by` for every fetch is something I wouldn't do for performance. DB triggers are used for different purposes to enforce important things on the database level to make sure no software bugs cause inconsistencies. If you ask me, I'd remove the whole thing related to these triggers but it would cost a lot of effort especially to prove that the original issue this feature was implemented for, will not show-up again. So my question is if there is any Rails feature to mark attribute outdated or not. So far it seems not.

Comment: *An additional find_by for every fetch is something I wouldn't do for performance* yes, in any case fetching attribute from database is extra `SELECT` query. `id` is indexed by default because usually it is PK, but still it is extra query